# eVis-Plugin centers mapwindow on coordinate origin

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mapwindow

I have a QGIS-project with layers loaded from a postgis-database and also some shapefiles. I use the eVis-Plugin to display pictures.
The displaying is working fine but after clicking on the geometry to open the eVis-Browser the mapwindow section always jumps to  the origin of the coordinatesystem (0/0). Also the asterisk from eVis showing which geometry is selected is located at (0/0)-but I don't have any geometries located there. Because of that I always have to zoom back to the map section with the geometries. How can I avoid this change of the mapwindow section?

I have this problem no matter if the path of the photo comes from a shapefile-layer or from the database.
The QGIS-project is defined with the coordinatesystem EPGS:21781 (CH1903, Switzerland). Because of that the geometries have coordinates like 600'000/200'000.

Comment: Can you clearly state what your problem is? Maybe an Image or two would help in showing us the problem.

Comment: sorry, I think I can't post images because I'm new to the forum..

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue using eVis. I first thought it was due to using the Dutch coordinate system (EPSG 28992). After selecting a feature with the Event ID-tool the map centered on 0,0, which in this case is somewhere near Paris.

The problem was that I was using a Multipoint layer from my PostGIS database.
After converting to Point geometries (single-part features) eVis started behaving as expected.